# Why is $ker(\phi)$ an ideal of $R$, when $\phi : R \longrightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

while studying Ring theory, I came across the following statement: "If $\phi : R \longrightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism, then $ker(\phi)$ is an ideal in $R$".

Looking at wikipedia, if $I$ is an ideal in $R$, then $\forall r \in R$, if  $i \in I$ then  $r \cdot i \in I$.

But if we let $r \in R$ such that $r \notin ker(\phi)$, then for any $i \in ker(\phi)$ we have:
$ker(r \cdot i)=ker(r) \cdot ker(i)=ker(r) \cdot e= ker(r) ≠ e$.
Therefore, $r \cdot i \notin I$ which is a contradiction.
Can anyone see what am I missing ?

Comment: You have mixed up the additive and multiplicative identity. $i\in \ker\phi$ means that $\phi(i)=0$, where $0$ is the *additive* identity.

Comment: Oh I see, it makes sense now. Thank you very much.